# clearing selection after running substitute command

Tags: vim

is there a way to clear highlighted text after running a substitute command in vim? For example, when I run:

```
:'<,'>s/<\([^>].*\)>/<!--\1-->/
```

to comment out the current line in an html file, after the command runs all of the text in the doc is highlighted and I have to hit the spacebar to clear the selection.

Is there anything I can add immediately after or as part of the substitute command so any selection is cleared automatically after the command runs so I don't have to hit the spacebar to clear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `<Space>` doesn't clear anything by default so you have it must have it mapped to something like `:nohl<CR>`. Therefore, you need to execute the command that you mapped to `<Space>` after your substitution.

This is done by "chaining" Ex commands with `|`:

```
:'<,'>s/<\([^>].*\)>/<!--\1-->/|nohl
```

Comment: yeap correct. I have space mapped like: `map <Space> :noh<CR>`. I did try chaining `:noh` with a semi-colon after the sub command, which of course didn't work, but the bar chain command works just as requested, except I have to run: `'<,'>s/<\([^>].*\)>/<!--\1-->/|:nohl` with the colon as well.